# Images do not display in HTML file

Tags: html, image, path

I uploaded my files to BlueHost file manager, uploaded my index.html file, and created relevant folders in the public_html folder. However, my images will not display at all when I load my website.

I tried copying the "document" root, and adding it to my index.html as follows:

```
<img src="~/public_html/assets/images/Olivias-birthdayparty-invite.png" height="500">,
```

but I still get a broken image icon when loading my website.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated! Note: Total beginner here. Just started learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I note that you created relevant folders inside public_html. That is the correct thing to do, but having done that you must ensure that your image tags are referencing the image in the correct folder.

If, for example, you placed your images inside a folder that is effectively like `public_html/images/bird.jpg`, then your image tag should reference that image *from the perspective of the index.html document*:

```
<img src="./images/bird.jpg">
```

or even just

```
<img src="images/bird.jpg">
```

will usually work.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got that to work. On my main page images are now showing up properly. However, for secondary HTML files that I have, writing the exact img element code is not working, and on those pages a broken image icon appears again. I don't get it.

Comment: Are the secondary html files located in a subfolder, or are they in the same folder as index.html? If they are in a subfolder, then you must again write the path from the perspective of the (secondary) html file, for example: `<img src="../images/bird2.jpg">` *(that is two periods instead of just one - it means "go up one level, and then change into the `images` folder, then get the bird2.jpg file)*.

Comment: Wow! what a duh moment! I just started learning about this stuff 2 days ago, and forgot about the difference between "." and ".."; thank you so much for your help, cssyphus. All your suggestions were very helpful! Problem solved :D